# jquery parent selector for expand links

Tags: jquery, css

I have a expand/collapse effect for accordions but when I click on the 1st panel expand button it expands all other panels also.

I want to open parent panel when clicking on the respective collapse links.

Here is my code

```
$('.stats-panel').hide();
       $(".expand a").click(function(){
           $(this).parent().toggleClass('collapse');
         $('.expand').parent().children().find('.stats-panel').slideToggle();
         $('.key-project-graph').slideToggle();
    });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ADUyuWAR/2/)**

PS- HTML structure can not be changed

Comment: `$('.expand')` matches all the panels. You should select something relative to `$(this)` if you only want this panel.

Comment: You got it right when calling `toggleClass()`, you need to do the same kind of thing for `slideToggle`.

Comment: Use $(event).closest('html element')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the selector `$('.expand')`

```
$(this).closest('.activity-block').find('.stats-panel').slideToggle();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5p5sN/)

If you want to expand only one item at a time then

```
var $target = $(this).closest('.activity-block').find('.stats-panel').stop(true, true).slideToggle();
$('.activity-block .stats-panel').not($target).stop(true, true).slideUp();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Kr6cU/)

Comment: Did u make any changes in html?

Answer (score 1):

try something like this,**[FIDDLE](http://jsbin.com/ADUyuWAR/4/)**

```
$('.stats-panel').hide();
   $(".expand a").click(function(){
       $(this).parent().toggleClass('collapse');
     $(this).parent().parent().children().find('.stats-panel').slideToggle();
     //$('.key-project-graph').slideToggle();
     return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with this line

```
 $('.expand').parent().children().find('.stats-panel').slideToggle();
```

You are using class selector which is looking all elements with same class name.  instead you have make use of **`this`** operator.

Since you want to access the parent of **`.expand`** from `.expand a` so try below

```
$(this).parent().parent().children().find('.stats-panel').slideToggle();
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsbin.com/ADUyuWAR/3#)